# iOS7 spellcheck bug in UITextView

Tags: ios7, uitextview, spell-checking, scrollable

I have editable UITextView that expands as I start writing into multiple rows. At some point the height of UITextView reaches predefined maximum height and becomes scrollable. While UITextView was not scrollable everything looked nice.

When text view becomes scrollable, weird thing starts happening with spellcheck underlining red dots. Details on attached image.

[image: first 4 lines were written while text view was not scrollable. Last 3 lines when text view was scrollable.]

Can anybody help me with this? I'm sure someone has encountered it so far.

Comment: Having this too, such a weird bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clearly a bug that was introduced in iOS 7 (still there for 7.0.6).

As soon as you make `UITextView` scrollable, spellchecker underlines are getting mashed. If you set

```
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

then it's fixed.

Solution is to put your text view into scroll view and resize scroll view's content size when text grows.

Here are some screenshots. I've also made views coloured so that you can see the bounds of all text view's subviews. Interesting that with `.scrollEnabled` set to YES text is inserted in some other `UIView` which height is being calculated wrong.

.scrollEnabled == YES

[image]
[image]

.scrollEnabled == NO

[image]

Comment: Crazy how this bug is still present in iOS 9!